# How do I put a link inside an array that is displayed through a function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, hyperlink

Ok so I have a textbox where, depending on which button you click, text from an array is displayed

```
var Text= new Array();

Text[1]="a"
Text[2]="b"
Text[3]="c"
function Anzeige(x) {
document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = Text[x];
}
.......
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="Anzeige(1)">
<input type="button" value="y" onclick="Anzeige(2)">
<input type="button" value="z" onclick="Anzeige(3)">
............
<div id="Anzeigefeld">
<div id="Text"></div>
</div>
```

So far so good, everything works as planned, but now I want to use a link like "`Text[1]="for more informations look <a style="color:blue;" href="insertlinkhere">here</a>`” and it just stops working (aka nothings happening when I click a button.

Help pls?

Comment: the onclick attribute is always javascript.

Comment: Probably it's about the quotes. Try `'for more informations look <a style="color:blue;" href="insertlinkhere">here</a>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape occurance of " as \"

```
Text[1]="for more informations look <a style=\"color:blue;\" href=\"insertlinkhere\">here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes, like `\"` or use single quotation marks `'` outside.

```js
var text = [
        '<a style="color:blue;" href="http://example.com/">here</a>',
        "<a style=\"color:red;\" href=\"http://example.com/\">here</a>",
        "c"
    ];

function anzeige(x) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text[x];
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="anzeige(0)">
<input type="button" value="y" onclick="anzeige(1)">
<input type="button" value="z" onclick="anzeige(2)">
<div id="anzeigefeld">
    <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, didnt post my original solution, I know that and tried '<a....a>' but for some reason it didnt work. However \" did it for me, so thanks to you and Angel Maharjan

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with the quote, you can fix it by changing the quote for the attributes. JS can differentiate the quotes and your link will start working.
so it will be 
    "Text[1]=for more informations look here”

Answer (score 0):

As the attributes of HTML elements are in double quotes, putting the entire string in single quotes can solve the problem.

```js
var Text = new Array();

Text[1] = 'for more informations look <a style="color:blue;" href="insertlinkhere">here</a>'
Text[2] = "b"
Text[3] = "c"

function Anzeige(x) {

  document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML = Text[x];
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="javascript:Anzeige(1)">
<input type="button" value="y" onclick="Anzeige(2)">
<input type="button" value="z" onclick="Anzeige(3)">
<div id="Anzeigefeld">
  <div id="Text"></div>
</div>
```